# Remove Remove Query Strings on static resources - Joomla

Tags: string, hyperlink, joomla3.0

I have this links that get generated when I compress my website:

http://example.com/compressed/css/css-5ade2.css?t=621

http://example.com/compressed/js/js-19af0.js?t=843

After I tested my website speed using GTmetrix, i get the advice to remove the queries from static resources.

These are compressed files, that Joomla Purity III template generates.

Can anyone let me know on how can I remove the query strings for css and js files in Joomla using htaccess or other tools if any available.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove them where? For what purpose? Your question is rather vague. Also, those look like cache-busting timestamps. You may want to keep them for that reason.

Comment: edited my question, sry for being vague on my q ... this files can't be cached because they have queries, that's what gtmetrix said after a speed test.

Comment: That's my point--something thinks that they shouldn't be cached, and so the queries are added. I'd start by finding out why.